# Jquery Slide to position on click

Tags: jquery

Here's a scenario...

I have a column.  In the column i have multiple divs with text inside each one.  A bit like a list of categories.  Which ever one is SELECTED gains a different background colour.

What i would like to be able to do is use jquery so that when a different div is clicked on the background colour appears to slide behind the rest of the items until it reaches the one you selected.

Does anyone have any idea if this can be done?  And if so any idea on Markup?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

There would be need to be a wrapper, a content container for each part and something that slides...

```
<div>
  <div class='slider'></div>
  <div>Content 1</div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post some markup, I am not seeing what you are after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting request :) You can do this with `.animate()` and a little bit of CSS, like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   <style type="text/css" >
    #content div { width: 200px; z-index: 2; }
    #content div.slider { position: absolute; background: #99AABB; z-index: -1; }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#content div:not(.slider)").click(function() {
   $(".slider").animate({ top: $(this).offset().top, height: $(this).height() });
  });
});
</script>
  <div id="content">
    <div class='slider'></div>
    <div>Content 1 Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test</div>
    <div>Content 2<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Try it out :) Just click on either div to see the effect.  [See a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ntZpG/)

The important bits:

- Ignore the `.slider` div in the click handler
- `.animate()` to same offset/height as destination div
- Lower `z-index` so it shows up as the background
- You could use an image, whatever's in the CSS for the `.slider` div will work

Comment: You legend!  Thats exactly what i was after.  Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Useful site as well that you had your demo on.

Comment: @Andy - Welcome! That was interesting to do, might end up using it myself somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it in the following approach...

Make sure your content divs have a transparent background and then create another div at the top of the list that is also transparent until the selected event occurs and then set it's background color so it appears but be sure that it's z-index is lower than that of the content divs... then you could look into using a library like scriptaculous to animate the div moving downward, you can get the position it needs to go to from the div that is marked selected so you know when to stop... I'm sure they have some cool velocity effects to make it a little more flashy (I am envisioning it quickly scrolling to its desired location and then slowly "locking" in to place)

Hope this helps your design planning some

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was hoping to stick with jquery.

Comment: Well you can omit the scriptaculous and simply use jQuery http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/